# Object is not defined when stubbing with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am very new to Jasmine. I am intending to use it for with vanilla javascript project. The initial configuration was a breeze but I am receiving object not defined error while using `spyOn`.

I have downloaded the version 3.4.0 [Jasmine Release Page](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/releases) and added the files 'as is' to my project. I then have changed `jasmine.json` file accordingly and see the all the example tests passing. However when try `spyOn` on a private object, I am getting undefined error,

```
if (typeof (DCA) == 'undefined') {
    DCA = {
        __namespace: true
    };
}
DCA.Audit = {
   //this function needs to be tested
   callAuditLogAction: function (parameters) {
        //Get an error saying D365 is not defined
        D365.API.ExecuteAction("bu_AuditReadAccess", parameters,
            function (result) { },
            function (error) {
                if (error != undefined && error.message != undefined) {
                    D365.Utility.alertDialog('An error occurred while trying to execute the Action. The response from server is:\n' + error.message);
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

and my spec class

```
describe('Audit', function(){
    var audit;
    beforeEach(function(){
        audit = DCA.Audit;
    })   
    describe('When calling Audit log function', function(){        
        beforeEach(function(){

        })
        it('Should call Execute Action', function(){
            var D365 = {
                API : {
                    ExecuteAction : function(){
                        console.log('called');
                    }
                }
            }

            // expectation is console log with say hello
            spyOn(D365.API, 'ExecuteAction').and.callFake(() => console.log('hello'));

            var params = audit.constructActionParameters("logicalName", "someId", 'someId');
            audit.callAuditLogAction(params);
        })
    })
})
```

As you can see my spec class does not know about actual `D365` object. I was hoping to stub the D365 object without having to inject it. Do I need to stub out whole 365 library and link it to my test runner html?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working after some pondering. So the library containing `D365` should still need to be added to my test runner html file. after that I can fake the method call like below,

```
it('Should call Execute Action', function(){            
        spyOn(D365.API, 'ExecuteAction').and.callFake(() => console.log('hello'));

        var params = audit.constructActionParameters("logicalName", "someId", 'someId');
        audit.callAuditLogAction(params);
    })
```

it is now working.